# How can I calculate distance of points in multi-dimension space from the centroid

Tags: r

I have centroid of space in 5 dimenions given as `centroid<-c(-0.0160560385542169, -0.0125691807228916, -0.000605079518072289, 
-0.00174781445783133, -0.0199511518072289)`. I also have a matrix with 5 samples where `PCA1:PCA5` represent 5 dimensions of points for those samples. How can I calculate the euclidean distance for each of these samples from the centroid? If it was the distance from one point to another, I could have simply done  `dist(mymat[,-1])`, but I am not sure how I can get the distance from the centroid. Can someone please suggest?

```
mymat<- structure(c("10687:G41F", "10687:SKDP-225.3", "10687:2671", "10687:LPH-001-16_SCC", 
"10687:MC1R-694CB-T", "-0.0039950", "-0.0203415", "-0.0200395", 
"-0.0147320", "-0.0196970", "-0.0140180", "-0.0181240", "-0.0165090", 
"-0.0148700", "-0.0170765", "-0.0136615", "-0.0010915", "-0.0014500", 
" 0.0020240", "-0.0021095", "-0.0002395", "-0.0019710", "-0.0017595", 
" 0.0036180", "-0.0036255", "-0.0184015", "-0.0197400", "-0.0238185", 
"-0.0282375", "-0.0323130"), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), c("samples", "PCA1", "PCA2", "PCA3", 
"PCA4", "PCA5")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dist should generalize to however many dimensions you want...

```
centroid <- c(-0.0160560385542169, -0.0125691807228916, -0.000605079518072289, 
 -0.00174781445783133, -0.0199511518072289)
rbind(c("centroid", centroid), mymat) -> k
dist(k, "euclidean") -> dd
as.matrix(dd) -> dd
k[,1] -> rownames(dd) 
as.data.frame(dd)
dd[2:6,1] -> dist_to_centroid
View(as.data.frame(dist_to_centroid))
```

Comment: Is it not different from the distance of these points from the centroid of the space (something what I want)?

Comment: Your code gives me distance from one point to another. Whereas, I want the distance of  these points from the centroid. Sorry I am confused with what you have done.

Comment: you want to know the distance from each of those points to the centroid, correct? if that is the case, then the code i gave should be correct. i don't understand the alternative question that you are referring to.

Comment: so you just need to subset the result to only include the entries that give the distance from one point to the centroid. do you know how to do this?